# Angularjs drag and drop using a single list

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an angular app in this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/zfFtb09E2utPwGDKChl6?p=preview).

Here i am trying to achieve a drag and drop functionality using just a single list.

Here is the app:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.people = [
      {'id':'1' ,'name':'John','category':'m'},
      {'id':'2', 'name':'Jack','category':'m'},
      {'id':'3','name':'Mark','category':'m'},
      {'id':'4','name':'Ernie','category':'m'},
      {'id':'5','name':'Jane','category':'w'},
      {'id':'6','name':'Jill','category':'w'},
      {'id':'7','name':'Betty','category':'w'},
      {'id':'8','name':'Mary','category':'w'}
      ];


      $scope.addText = "";


      $scope.dropSuccessHandler = function($event,index,array){
          //array[index].category='w';
          //findAndRemove(array, id, pid);
      //    alert(index, array[index]);
          array.splice(index,1);
      };


      $scope.onDrop = function($event,$data,array){
         // $data.category='m';

         // $scope.people.splice($scope.people.indexOf($data.id), 1);

          $scope.people.push($data);
          //array.push($data);
      };

});
```

The problem is, the controller is getting thoroughly confused when i am trying to drop an element from the right to the left. The splice command is deleting the wrong name. It works fine when we drop an element from the left to the right.

How do i get around this?

Answer (score 0):

When you drag an item in the list on the right, the `index` parameter handed to your `dropSuccessHandler` function is the index of the element of the list on the right, not the index into the actual javascript array. So Jane is index 0, Jill is index 1, etc. Thus if you drag Jill, the `dropSuccessHandler` function removes the element of the array at index 1, i.e. Jack.